# Simple HTML5-JS page is freezing with DT unresponsive

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[Here](http://hastebin.com/evewirahet.lua) is my HTML file, meant to simulate a 3-sphere. When I run it, the page freezes. The Chrome DevTools won't accept any command. Is there an infinite loop that I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

I can't post this on a comment, but have you checked this? You have two while loops, and one is nested... I may be wrong, the code is hard to follow.

**Updated (Clarification thanks to Brian):**

In the inner loop isClose is compared to some calculation (no assignment done) which if evaluates as true exits the inner loop. After this conditional no assignment is performed on either isClose or on any variables within the first conditional. So if the inner loop isn't exit on the first pass it never will :)

```
while (true) {
                        isClose = !isClose;
                        p0     = project(obj.vertices[ obj.faces[f][v-1] ]);
                        p1     = project(obj.vertices[ obj.faces[f][ v ] ]);
                        factor = (5000 - p1[0] - p1[1]) / (p1[0] + p1[1] - p0[0] - p0[1]);
                        p01    = [p1[0] + factor * (p1[0] - p0[0]), p1[1] + factor * (p1[1] - p0[1])];
                        polygon = [p01, p1];
                        while (true) {
                            v++;
                            if (isClose != obj.vertices[ obj.faces[f][v % obj.faces[f].length] ][2] > -Math.PI/2)
                                break;
                            polygon[polygon.length] = project(obj.vertices[ obj.faces[f][v % obj.faces[f].length] ]);
                        }
                        p0     = project(obj.vertices[ obj.faces[f][  v   % obj.faces[f].length] ]);
                        p1     = project(obj.vertices[ obj.faces[f][(v-1) % obj.faces[f].length] ]);
                        factor = (5000 - p1[0] - p1[1]) / (p1[0] + p1[1] - p0[0] - p0[1]);
                        p01    = p1 + factor * (p1 - p0);
                        polygon[polygon.length] = p01;
                        if (is_clockwise(polygon)) {
                            p1 = polygon[         0        ];
                            pN = polygon[polygon.length - 1];
                            factor = 5000 / (p1[0] + pN[0] + p1[1] + pN[1]);
                            p0 = [factor * (p1[0] + pN[0]), factor * (p1[1] + pN[1])];
                            polygon[polygon.length] = p0;
                            draw(polygon, obj.colour);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: You're correct - there's an inner loop which contains a `break;` statement once isClose gets set to false (either first or second iteration depending on the initial value) the second loop will continue indefinitely. I assume the example posted was originally part of the question.

Comment: Yes, it's a fragment from the code provided by the user... it's very large, and not so easy to follow for a non-good programmer like me hahah

Maybe you can post a more detailed answer than me! Abrazo :)

Comment: Feel free to update your answer with my clarifications - you were right I think I was just confirming it.

Essentially why I say it likely loops indefinitely is initially isClose is set to !isClose so it looks like a boolean flag.

In the inner loop isClose is compared to some calculation (no assignment done) which if evaluates as true exits the inner loop.

After this conditional no assignment is performed on either isClose or on any variables within the first conditional. 

So if the inner loop isn't exit on the first pass it never will :)

Sorry about formatting on the comment

Comment: Notice the `v++` at the start of the inner loop. From earlier in the code, we know that the expression differs for certain values of v. Thus, the inner loop should halt.

Answer (score 1):

### The dreaded infinite loop.

Every javascript programer is struck from time to time with a locked tab and no easy exit.

If you have the dev tools open you can use the debugger and pause execution, then set a variable to the exit condition.

Example

```
for(var i = 100; i >= 0; i++){ // force of habit ++ has a infinite loop
     // do stuff
}
```

The loop will not exit but if the devtools is up. Go to the debugger panel and click pause. Then add to the watch list `i=-2`. This will set i to the exit condition. Unpause and the loop will exit.

If not in devtools you are stuck and all you can do is close the tab or force it to crash (halt process). To halt the process in Chrome hit [shift][esc] or use `menu->More tools->Task manager` to open the task menu. Select the task from the list of running tabs and apps, then click `End process` This will stop the execution and clear the tab (The tab will show "Aw, snap!")

Or you can wait for the popup that will appear when the script is blocking for too long and click "kill"

It is very frustrating that javascript does this. It pays that when writing and testing loops with indeterminate exit conditions to add an additional exit clause.

```
while(true){
    if(someThingMayHappen === true){
         break;
     }
}
```

This can be a problem during development. The something may never happen and you are then locked out. As a safeguard add a fail safe

```
var counter = 0;
while(counter < 10000){
    counter += 1;
    if(someThingMayHappen === true){
         break;
     }
}
```

Now if there is a bug your code will still exit and you can track down the bug more easily. You can remove the counter once you are satisfied your code is running correctly.

From a professional standpoint I would never accept a bit of code that does not have an exit condition in the loop statement. "break" and "continue" are in reality goto statements and make your code harder to read.

Another reason to avoid `while(true)` is that it confuses the optimisation code. It needs a clear exit condition, and if you obfuscate the exit condition with a `break` it will just give up and mark, not just the loop, but the whole function and associated functions as "Not for optimisation" which is not a good thing.Ref [Infinite loops with deep logic exit conditions or unclear exit conditions](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#6-infinite-loops-with-deep-logic-exit-conditions-or-unclear-exit-conditions)

Even if you want to use a break to exit, trick the javascript engine by adding a fake exit condition.

```
var loop = true;
while(loop){
    if(exitCondition){
        loop = false; // not needed but for makes the optimiser happy.
        break;
    }

}
```

This will prevent the code from being marked "Not for optimization"

Comment: Both loops seem to be functioning happily.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the inner while loop, but with the outer one. It didn't have an exit condition.